# Cannot log in on Youtube iPad app

Tags: iphone, ipad, ipod, youtube

I get an `Authentication failed` error when I try to log in to the Youtube iPad app. But the same username and password work on Youtube Safari and other browsers.

Comment: My mom is having the same issue. she can log into YouTube.com, but not into the YouTube app. I am able to log into the app on her iPad 2 with MY account, but as soon as I log out and try to log her into the app, it gives the same user authentication failed message. Any help would be appreciated. I can't figure out why it will let me in and not her. (I did make sure I signed out before trying to log her in again.)

Comment: I have a similar issue. I can login using the browser, but the YouTube App says that the username and/or password are incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have two-factor authentication enabled on your Google account? If so, you may have to create an application-specific password for the YouTube login.

http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=184968